# Cannot import tab delimited file with unusual characters in SAS

Tags: sas

Hi I am trying to export a tab delimited file in SAS that looks like this,

Names   Points
Sumit1  10
Sumit2  20
SUmit4  30
SUmit5  85
SUmit6  90
SUmit7  39
hfg├╢┬«q-┬▒├▓S├Ç┬«t├⌐├«├ôVU┬½┬æ├«j'n5E┬òd├╖Yb#┬¡┬ÅAK$┬«S┬Ä┬å├┐-├â┬ìK├òw┬┐├│├Ñ0"┬ñh┬ùt0Ld  89
SUmit8  48
SUmit9  70
SUmit10 20
SUmit11 90

I am using the following code to import the file,

```
data names;
infile "C:xxxxxxxx\names.txt" 
delimiter='09'x MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2;
informat names $150.;
informat Points best32.;
format names $150.;
format Points best12.;
input names $
Points;
run;
```

and the sas data set after import looks like the following:

Names                                             Points
Sumit1                                           10
Sumit2                                           20
SUmit4                                           30
SUmit5                                           85
SUmit6                                           90
SUmit7                                               39
hfg├╢┬«q-┬▒├▓S├Ç┬«t├⌐├«├ôVU┬½┬æ├«j'n5E┬òd├╖Yb#┬¡┬ÅAK$┬«S┬Ä┬å├┐-├â┬ìK├òw┬┐├│├Ñ0"┬ñh┬ùt0Ld  .

So basically all the rows are not getting imported in sas and it stops because of the presence of some unusual characters
(I don't know what what this characters are called) in row 7.

There are 1000 files like this that I need to import. So I am using a macro to import the files.
Can somebody please help me how can I import this type of files in SAS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot import text limitd file with unusual characters in SAS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861944/cannot-import-text-limitd-file-with-unusual-characters-in-sas)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.....Change the lengths accordingly...

```
DATA names;
LENGTH Names $ 91 Points 8 ;
FORMAT Names  $CHAR91. Points  BEST2. ;
INFORMAT Names  $CHAR91. Points           BEST2. ;
INFILE 'C:xxxxxxxx\names.txt'
LRECL=32767 ENCODING="LATIN1" TERMSTR=CRLF DLM='09'x MISSOVER DSD ;
INPUT Names : $CHAR91. Points : ?? BEST2. ;
RUN;
```