# Cannot import text delimited file with unusual characters in SAS

Tags: sas

Hi I am trying to import a tab delimited file in SAS that looks like this,

```
Names   Points
Sumit1  10
Sumit2  20
SUmit4  30
SUmit5  85
SUmit6  90
SUmit7  39
hfg├╢┬«q-┬▒├▓S├Ç┬«t├⌐├«├ôVU┬½┬æ├«j'n5E┬òd├╖Yb#┬¡┬ÅAK$┬«S┬Ä┬å├┐-├â┬ìK├òw┬┐├│├Ñ0"┬ñh┬ùt0Ld        89
SUmit8  48
SUmit9  70
SUmit10 20
SUmit11 90
```

The first row represents column names.

I am using the following code to import the file,

```
data names;
infile "C:xxxxxxxx\names.txt" 
delimiter='09'x MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2;
informat names $150.;
informat Points best32.;
format names $150.;
format Points best12.;
input names $
Points;
run;
```

and the sas data set after import looks like the following:

```
Names                                                     Points
Sumit1                                                  10
Sumit2                                                  20
SUmit4                                                  30
SUmit5                                                  85
SUmit6                                                  90
SUmit7                                                      39
hfg├╢┬«q-┬▒├▓S├Ç┬«t├⌐├«├ôVU┬½┬æ├«j'n5E┬òd├╖Yb#┬¡┬ÅAK$┬«S┬Ä┬å├┐-├â┬ìK├òw┬┐├│├Ñ0"┬ñh┬ùt0Ld             .
```

So basically all the rows are not getting imported in sas and it stops at row 7 because of the presence of some unusual characters
(I don't know what what this characters are called).

There are 1000 files like this that I need to import. So I am using a macro to import the files.
Can somebody please help me how can I import this type of files in SAS.

Comment: Can you list any errors or warnings or notes in your log?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
DATA names;
LENGTH Names $ 91 Points 8 ;
FORMAT Names  $CHAR91. Points  BEST2. ;
INFORMAT Names  $CHAR91. Points           BEST2. ;
INFILE 'C:xxxxxxxx\names.txt'
LRECL=32767 ENCODING="LATIN1" TERMSTR=CRLF DLM='7F'x MISSOVER DSD ;
INPUT Names : $CHAR91. Points : ?? BEST2. ;
RUN;
```